# How can I remain input data when it was error with validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

It validates before update or create record if input captcha was correct.
My codes take me back to previous page but all of the input data is gone....
How can I remain the input data that was typed in at previous page?

I'd like to use before_filter and apply these 2 actions 'update' and 'create'

**controller**

```
before_filter :simple_captcha_check, :only => [:update, :create] 

def simple_captcha_check
    if !simple_captcha_valid?
        flash[:error] = 'Wrong Captcha!'
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You should ideally have a common update/create form partial that is rendered from both `edit` and `new` views. With such a design you can just render that common partial with local parameters to fill in the form again. These values would be the same that your action received after submitting the form.

**Approach 2:**

Submit your form using ajax. Before submitting, make an ajax call to `simple_captcha_check` and finally submit the form if it returns success.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes I do have the same _form.html.erb in common.  But the problem is what I should have instead of redirect_to :back.  Otherwise I have to decide action where to go after error.  Is there anyway to manage this?

Comment: instead of redirect_to line, use render method as follows: 
render :partial=>"form", locals=>{:name=>"My Name"}

Comment: You can have a look at section 3.4 in following link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Yes. Specifically, section 3.4.4 Passing Local Variables

Comment: Thank you very much. I've read whole part of that. But I still cannot figure out what's good way in my case:( Sorry about my poor brainstorming

Answer (score 1):

You should not **redirect** page when validation error happened, you should just **render** with the input template.

Comment: Thanks but in my case, how can I judge what to render? it could be edit or new.